# Creating a Redshift user with a sha256 password

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

According to the redshift [CREATE USER](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_USER.html) documentation, you can create a user and provide their password as a sha256 encrypted string with a salt, for example:

```sql
CREATE USER admin PASSWORD 'sha256|fe95f2bc7c4a111b6f0f7d0b60bfedd1935fb295f8dce1d62708ab8d2f564baf|c721bff5d9042cf541ff7b9d48fa8a6e545c19a763e3710151f9513038b0f6c6';
```

where the syntax for the PASSWORD portion is:
`'sha256|digest|256-bit-salt'`

The documentation is a bit light on details about how exactly to do this and my attempts keep failing. I assume that the 256-bit-salt should either be concatenated to the beginning or end of the plain-text password and then hashed like the following:

given a 256-bit salt of `c721bff5d9042cf541ff7b9d48fa8a6e545c19a763e3710151f9513038b0f6c6` and a password of `ChangeThisPassword123!`

I can create the sha256 digest by running the following in redshift:

```sql
select sha2('ChangeThisPassword123!c721bff5d9042cf541ff7b9d48fa8a6e545c19a763e3710151f9513038b0f6c6', 256);
```

which gives me a digest of `28c73049ec678db8b975a0efd140c60491b6e9b1124fb62dd65c35075e89de0e`.

So I should be able to create a user with the following sql:

```sql
CREATE USER exampleuser PASSWORD 'sha256|28c73049ec678db8b975a0efd140c60491b6e9b1124fb62dd65c35075e89de0e|c721bff5d9042cf541ff7b9d48fa8a6e545c19a763e3710151f9513038b0f6c6';
```

However, when I try to login as this user with the password `ChangeThisPassword123!` I get a bad password error!

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here? I've tried putting the salt at the beginning of the password before creating the digest too but no luck.

Comment: You are correct -- there is no explanation of how the Salt should be used. Did you try pre-pending the Salt instead? (That is, putting it at the start instead of the end?)

Comment: Yeah I tried sticking the salt are the start too but same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spoke to Amazon support and they have given me a solution. The problem was that I was creating a hex digest using the character representation of the salt but when creating the digest it needs to use the binary representation of it.

Redshift must take the hex salt that you provide in the `create user` statement and convert it to binary before storing it as the actual salt?

So, for the example above I needed to use python to solve this as you cannot pass in a binary value to the redshift sha256 function:

**1) Using python, create the hex digest using the the password + salt**

```py
import binascii
from hashlib import sha256

salt = "c721bff5d9042cf541ff7b9d48fa8a6e545c19a763e3710151f9513038b0f6c6"
salt_binary = binascii.unhexlify(salt)

print(sha256(b"ChangeThisPassword123!" + salt_binary).hexdigest())
```

which prints out:

> 4ae3250e18695757a15dd7f6749ca2b03c756f11fae99f9cd534698832d19b39

**2. Now create the user in redshift using the `create user` command with the correct hex digest + salt**:

```sql
CREATE USER exampleuser PASSWORD 'sha256|4ae3250e18695757a15dd7f6749ca2b03c756f11fae99f9cd534698832d19b39|c721bff5d9042cf541ff7b9d48fa8a6e545c19a763e3710151f9513038b0f6c6';
```

**3. Login to redshift with username `exampleuser` and password `ChangeThisPassword123!`**

Thanks to the AWS support for this answer! I've submitted feedback for them to update the documentation to make it clearer.

Comment: Great to have this documented now!